# Why the electrode that is the electron source on a x-ray tube is called cathode?

Tags: electrochemistry, analytical-chemistry, spectroscopy, elemental-analysis

In electrochemistry, the electrode that lose electrons and oxidizes is called anode. Why on an x-ray tube the electrode that lose electrons is called cathode?

Comment: In an electrolytic cell, the cathode is negative: it supplies the electrons to reduce electroactive species. In a voltaic cell, the anode is negative.

Comment: Because it loses electrons.

Comment: You're contradicting yourself...

Comment: @Mithoron Why am I contradicting myself?

Comment: @TitoMorennoPonteseSouza Can you re-phrase your query? The title says cathode, the text says anode! What is your exact question?

Answer (score 3):

In solution or in vacuum (i.e. not in the wire), cations travel to the cathode and anions travel to the anode. Electrons in the vacuum are like anions (negatively charged), so they are emitted from the cathode and travel to the anode. However, in the wire, electrons travel from the anode back to the cathode.

The definitions are similar for a cathode ray tube (old style TV or oscilloscope). Here, the electrons creating the image are generated in the glowing cathode. They never make it to the anode but fly through it to reach the screen.

[image]
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b0/Cathode_ray_Tube.PNG

Answer (score 2):

In BOTH electrochemistry and X-ray tube context:

- The electrode that "looses electrons" toward the external circuit is called the anode.
- The electrode that "looses electrons" toward the system (an electrolytic cell or an X-ray tube) is called the cathode.

The point is that the direction of "electron loosing" is opposite in these two cases.

---

There is one exception in cathode-anode electrode marking, taken rather from the practical engineering point of view than theoretical electrochemical one.

For the case of rechargeable galvanic cells ( like Li-Ion, Ni-Cd/MH, lead acid etc.), the cathode/anode is permanently assigned to the electrode being the cathode/anode at the galvanic stage - discharging. This was probably chosen to avoid confusion, because from the electrochemical point of view, anode-cathode marking mutually switch the place and relative potentials when switching between discharging and charging.

By other words, cell researchers and developers approach secondary cells -- in the electrode naming context -- like if they were just primary cells and if recharge ability was just secondary detail. I.e. cathodes are for them the more positive electrodes.

Therefore, in the Li-Ion cells engineering context, the graphite-lithium [intercalate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphite_intercalation_compound) electrode is always the anode and the mixed-oxide electrode is always the cathode, regardless of fact that it is the opposite during charging in the electrochemical context.

Comment: Poutnik, The marking on rechargeable batteries is just a commercial practice (for the everyday user) not an electrochemical convention. Imagine, it took 150 years for electrochemists to sort this out what will happen to the common user. This is why manufacturers will also color code the wires. Scientifically, the fixed sign is wrong. Electrochemically, the labels must change during use and recharge as you stated.

Comment: @M.Farooq  Not overlapping domains feels fine with not compatible own term definitions. I have explicitly commented it is engineering  point of view, so saying it is wrong is - wrong, as it is not using electrochemical definition. It is not commercial practice for everyday user either - they do not care. It is for cell developers and researchers. There regularly refer to electrodes in their papers as the anode/cathode without further explanation what they mean by it, because it is clear to them and to the targetted readers.